Find the Cosine of the Angle Between the Plane $(MND)$ and the Plane $(ABC)$
The problem
Consider the cube $ABCDA'B'C'D'$. Let $M$ be the middle of $AA'$ and $N$ the middle of $B'C'$.
a) Determine the tangent of the angle between $AD'$ and $MN$
b) Find the cosine of the angle between the plane $(MND)$ and the plane $(ABC)$
my idea
drawing
I let $O$ be the midpoint of $BC'$
because $NO|| AA'$ and $NO=MA$ then $NOAM$ is a parallelogram $=> MN||AO$ and we also know that $AD'||BC'$ so $\angle(AD',MN)= \angle(BC',AO)= \angle OAB$
In right angle triangle OAB we can calculate the tangent of the wanted angle as $= \frac{OB}{AB}= \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$
For point b) because $(ABC)||(A'B'C')=> \angle((DNM),(ABC))=\angle((DNM),(A'B'C'))$
I let $DM \cap A'D'={Y}, Y \in A'D'$ so we know that $(DNM) \cap (A'B'C')=YN$
I let $D'Z \perp YN$ and because $DD'\perp (A'B'C'D')$ by the thorem of the 3 perpendicular we get that $DZ\perp YN$ so $\angle((DNM),(ABC))=\angle((DNM),(A'B'C'))=\angle D'ZD$
In the right-angled triangle, we can calculate the cosine of the wanted angle $=\frac{4 \sqrt{13}}{13}$
I put this at solution-verification because I'm not sure if I calculated the tangent and the cosine correctly and I'm not sure if this part is right, because $(ABC)||(A'B'C')=> \angle((DNM),(ABC))=\angle((DNM),(A'B'C'))$"
I hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Can be determined using vectors?

@Narasimham Heyyy, i dont really know much abiut vectors. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Find coordinates of all vertices of the cube. Use vector product to find cos of angle between vectors connecting desired points.

@Narasimham Is my solution right tho?

@RyanPamMunoz you can do the orthogonal projection of $\triangle MND$ on the plane $ABC$. The ratio of the areas of $\triangle MND$ to its orthogonal projection is the inverse of the cosine of the dihedral angle you want

@hellofriends Thanks for your idea! May i ask if my idea is right tho?

a)

$\angle(AD',MN)= \angle(BC',AO)= \angle OAB$

I think this should be
$$\angle(AD',MN)= \angle(BC',AO)= \color{red}{\angle{AOB}}$$
Then, the tangent of the wanted angle is equal to $\frac{AB}{BO}=\color{red}{\sqrt 2}$.

b)

In the right-angled triangle, we can calculate the cosine of the wanted angle $=\frac{4 \sqrt{13}}{13}$

I think this is not correct.
Considering the right triangle $\triangle{DZD'}$ with $\angle{ZD'D}=90^\circ$, we have $$\cos\angle{D'ZD}=\frac{D'Z}{DZ}=\color{red}{\frac{4\sqrt{29}}{29}}$$
(You wrote $\frac{4\sqrt{13}}{13}$ which is equal to $\frac{D'Z}{DD'}$.)

I'm not sure if this part is right, because $(ABC)||(A'B'C')=> \angle((DNM),(ABC))=\angle((DNM),(A'B'C'))$"

The part is correct.

As mathlove pointed out, in part a, $\tan \angle AOB=\frac{AB}{OB}=\frac1{\tfrac1{\sqrt2}}=\sqrt2$ and in part b, $D'Z=\frac4{\sqrt{13}}$, $YD=\sqrt5$, $DZ=\sqrt{YD^2-YZ^2}=\frac{\sqrt{29}}{\sqrt{13}}$ and hence $\cos\angle DZD'=\frac{D'Z}{DZ}=\frac4{\sqrt{29}}.$
As pointed out in the comments, we can use vectors to solve such questions without thinking about the picture much, although the solution is not artistically pleasing compared to the geometric solutions.
Lebel the cube such that $A=(0,0,0)$, $B=(1,0,0)$ and $C'=(1,1,1)$. Then $M=(0,0,\frac12)$, $N=(1,\frac12,1)$, $D'=(0,1,1)$.
a. Hence, the required vectors are $\vec{MN}=\langle1,\frac12,\frac12\rangle$ and $\vec{AD'}=\langle0,1,1\rangle.$ The cosine of the angle between them is $\frac{\vec{MN}\cdot\vec{AD'}}{||\vec{MN}||||\vec{AD'}||}=\frac1{\sqrt3}.$ So, the tangent of that angle is $\sqrt2$, since it is acute angle.
b. Since $D=(0,1,0)$, $\vec{MD}=\langle0,1,-\frac12\rangle$ and a normal vector of the plane $(DMN)$ is $n_1=\vec{MD}\times\vec{MN}=\langle-\frac34,\frac12,-1\rangle.$ On the other hand, a normal vector of $(ABC)$ is $n_2=\langle0,0,1\rangle.$
The cosine of the acute angle between the planes is then
$$\frac{|n_1\cdot n_2|}{||n_1|||n_2||}=\frac4{\sqrt{29}}.$$
